# Dimmer + LED light bulb + resistor = Ohm's Law Broken

Tags: led, current, resistance, dimmer

**CIRCUIT:** A 12 volt battery powers a dimmer. The output of the dimmer powers 4 LED light bulbs. They are all in parallel: 6W + 2W + 2W + 2W. The 6W bulb is a spotlight. The 2W light bulbs are under cabinet puck lights. All bulbs are dimmable. This is tested and verified. The dimmer varies its output from 0 - 12 V and all of the bulbs brighten and dim together in unison.

**PROBLEM:** The 6W spot light, mounted on the ceiling, is much brighter than the other lights. I would like to keep that bulb on the same dimmer but have it be less bright.

**IDEA:** How about adding a resistor in series with the 6W bulb to reduce the voltage/current, which will cause the bulb to dim?

**PLAN:** I used my multi-meter to measure the current flowing to the 6W bulb: 0.5 A. Using Ohm's Law, I reckoned that by adding a 5 Ω resistor in series with my bulb I can effect a voltage drop which should reduce the brightness of the bulb. I added a 5 Ω resistor in series to the bulb.

**RESULT:** The 6W bulb does get slightly dimmer. My ceramic resistor gets "toasty". HOWEVER - my multi-meter now reads 1.2 A for the wire going to the resistor and bulb. This took me completely by surprise. I thought the current would go down to 0.4 A, not up to 1.2 A.

What on earth is going on? Anyone want to take a guess?

Comment: TRIAC + battery = does not compute.

Comment: It's already been answered about the current draw increasing do to the LED compensating for the losses introduced by the resistor. But if you want the lights to have the same brightness, why not use lights of equal power? Use all 2W LEDs instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, Ohm's law stands. There's also no need to guess what is happening, this is pretty clear:

A lightbulb just simply isn't a simple resistor.

Incandescent light bulbs are approximately constant power sinks, due to the nature of their filament heating up until a thermal equilibrium is reached, which happens at a fixed power.

LED lightbulbs typically have an internal switch-mode power supply and are by design pretty good constant power sinks; their job is to supply the internal LEDs with a constant current at approximately constant voltage, and thus drive them at approximately constant power.

If you draw constant power through a load, adding a series resistor, thus lowering the voltage across the load, the current will go up, as power is the product of current and voltage.

So, it's not Ohm's law that's broken. You just don't realize you're out of line trying to apply it here.

Comment: Just for my own edification: my dimmer is of a modern switching (on-off) type, not the old rheostat kind. Can you tell me the proper name for that (apparently not TRIAC). Thanks?  So - my trick might have worked for an incandescent light bulb but - not a sneaky "smart" LED bulb that wants more power?!

Comment: no, it would *not* have worked. I explitly mention that! (I don't know actually what your dimmer does – but I think if you call it "switching", that's a good name; others would probably be "PWM controller")

Comment: I see you updated your answer. I like your explanation. I figured the bulb (circuitry) might be doing something like you describe but I'm not an electrical engineer, so I wanted to hear about it from someone like you! I am waiting for a genius to tell me the other answer, which is to buy a lower wattage bulb, which I did try but, it has a nasty yellow hue to it (even though it has the same 2700K temperature and CRI listed). Yikes! I might try a diffuser under the bulb instead or just live with it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but incandescent bulbs *are* dimmable, how does that work then? Wouldn't they temporally average the dimming modulation?

Comment: oh, keen observation! Due to the switching, the thermal equilibrium that is reached changes. You got me there!

Comment: @MarcusMüller after giving it a thought, I think incandescent bulbs can't be constant power sinks, otherwise they wouldn't be dimmable. Indeed I see I/V graphs of the shape I=sqrt(V) for incandescent bulbs, whereas a constant power sink would have I=k/V. That does make them nonlinear and therefore non-Ohmic though.

Comment: yeah, as said, the fact that you're switching them off regularly changes the amount of heat they can lose relative to that they can at most produce; that shifts the operational point! Bulbs do have that self-regulating behaviour where the heating of the filament increases the resistance, which leads to less current through the filament, which leads to less heating. If that wasn't the case, they would be fuses and burn every time, because if you measure a cold incandescent bulb's resistance and assume that remains the same when hot, you'd get *dangerous* currents during operation :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller my point is, I think your comment earlier in this thread is not correct — *yes*, a resistor would have worked to dim an incandescent light bulb, because an incandescent bulb is *not* approximately a constant power sink. The equilibrium power varies with input voltage.

Comment: it varies very little with benign variatons of input voltage, @DamienD. It varies a lot if you force the bulb off for a percentage of the cycle. A dimmer doesn't modify the instantaneous voltage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the I/V curve of a bulb has a positive slope throughout as far as I can tell. So if you double the voltage you will *at least* double the power. Here's my problem with your answer and comments. The current in the OP's circuit went UP after adding a resistor because of the LED driver, which has a region of negative I/V slope. Your answer says that, but also seems to say that an incandescent bulb has a similar behaviour. The OP asks, would it have gone down with an incandescent bulb?, and your reply is 'no'. This is simply not true; the current would _indeed_ have gone down.

Comment: Okay race fans! I had to know, so I ran a little test: dimmer output = 12.4 volts (it's on my camper). Old 1141 side marker bulb rated at 18.4 watts supposedly. I hook it up and notice the bulb is nice and bright. Mr. multi-meter reads 1.3 amps. Next, I put my 5 ohm ceramic resistor in circuit (series of course). Mr. bulb is not happy - he is dimmer but still lit. My multi-meter now reads exactly 1.0 amps. Conclusion: an incandescent bulb will dim in this case but, my smart LED bulb will not because he is too clever for me. Everyone have a great night - thank you for your comments!